# Automated Redmine test reports from Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, report, redmine, junit5

1. What is the best way to export JUnit 5 **test reports** to my
   **Redmine** repository?
2. Does anybody know if there are some **Android Studio** plug-in's for this task?

Answer (score 0):

- Can be solved just by **parsing** junit **index.html test report** and
  sending per **rest api**
- I didn't find some Android Studio plugins for this task.